# Non Capturing default group in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a message pattern like:

> building three room two rack fifteen

I need to extract the locations from this message. So, I have created the following regular expression for first location:

```
^building (?<loc1>[\w ]+)room[\w ]*$
```

It's getting the location one, but I am getting it as the second group whereas I am expecting it as the first group..

Groups that my expression return are:

> group[0] : building three room two rack fifteen
>
> group[1] : three

Simply, I don't want the first group, instead I want the location to be the first group. Something like:

> group[0] : three

I have tried non capturing groups, but not worked. Please let me know, how can I  achieve this?

Comment: Can you please accept and bring a closure to this question

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=^building )(?<loc1>[\w ]+)(?= room)
```

You can use `lookarounds` to get that.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/2

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding some explanation as to why is this happening and why lookarounds are bypassing this (it might not be known to someone who begins working with Regexes). Other than that, your answer is pretty good and straightforward.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice... But the improvement could be beneficial to anyone who stumbles upon it when searching from the Internet :)